# How to check if first record end date is greater than other record start date in Java?

Tags: java

Now, I just enhance the Java application and control the application form. The function will avoid the user to enter the wrong date. The condition as follow:

Expected result:

Start Date        End Date

01-APR-2018     03-APR-2018
04-APR-2018     07-APR-2018

Show the error message: The secord record start date cannot greater than first record end date.

I try to compile the program but no any errors. Then, the function is not work.

```
public boolean CheckDateRecord(ExceptionGenerator eg, int dateCount, Date date, Date pstartdate, Date penddate, int id)  throws Exception {
            boolean CheckDate = false; 
  for (int i=1;i<=dateCount;i++)
    {
        Date date = hd.getdate( i );
        Date startdate = date.getData(1);   // Get Start Date
        Date enddate = date.getData(2);     // Get End Date     

                if (id != i &&

                           //check the record end date cannot greater than start date condition

            ((startdate.getValue().compareTo(pstartdate.getValue()) > 0 && 
              pstartdate.getValue().compareTo(penddate.getValue()) > 0
              ) ))
        {
            CheckDate = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    return CheckDate;

         }
```

Comment: What is `Date.getValue()`? That's not a method on the standard `Date` class.

Comment: Date.getValue() = 02/10/2018 (format: DD/MM/YYYY)

Comment: I might miss something due to the awful formatting but `startdate.getValue().compareTo(pstartdate.getValue()) > 0 &&            pstartdate.getValue().compareTo(penddate.getValue()) > 0` will always be `false`

Comment: Date is not java.util.Date is it? This is some weird custom date class, so you are on your own with that.